# SQL statement using special charter

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, character

Can anyone please help me in correcting below statement:

```
SET @cmd='BULK INSERT ' + @Database + '.dbo.' + @tmp + ' from ' + @Out + @tmp + '.csv 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = , , ROWTERMINATOR = \n)'
```

Output of the above query is:

> BULK INSERT MP2.dbo.GLCODE from C:\SABA\GLCODE.csv WITH
>   (FIELDTERMINATOR = , , ROWTERMINATOR = \n)

I want to print this in below manner:

> BULK INSERT MP2.dbo.GLCODE from C:\SABA\GLCODE.csv WITH
>   (FIELDTERMINATOR =',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

Comment: Are you doing this concatenation in php or doing in sqlserver?

Comment: @Sami I think yes. there's a `dbo` on the query..hehe

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET @cmd='BULK INSERT ' + @Database + '.dbo.' + @tmp + ' from ' + @Out + @tmp + 
            '.csv WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','' , ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'
```

Simply use `''` which is used as a escape sequence character to get an extra `'`

Comment: Already tried Yogi before posting it here. tried different combination including the one you mentioned but it is not working.

Comment: @Sami doing this in SqlServer 2000 :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @cmd='BULK INSERT ' + @Database + '.dbo.' + @tmp + ' from ''' + @Out + @tmp + '.csv'' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'
```

Yogi's suggested approach should work but you will also need to put apostrophes around the filename.